# json api not working in server

Tags: json, api

i am develop one bitcoin website, i m include the live price tricket, it is working in localhost, when i upload in sever it is not working the code is

```
<?php

$f="http://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice/INR.json";

$file=file_get_contents($f);

$myjson = json_decode($file);
print "<li>BPI:".$myjson->bpi->INR->rate;
print "<li>disclaimer:".$myjson->disclaimer;


?>
```

in local i m get result this 
[image]

after upload i m get this result

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Check whether `allow_url_fopen` is set `true` in PHP on your live server. If is `false` ask your server hosting support to set it to `true`

If server doesn't allow making it `true` you can try following

```
$url = "http://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice/INR.json";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$contents = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo curl_error($ch);
    echo "\n<br />";
    $contents = '';
} else {
    curl_close($ch);
}

if (!is_string($contents) || !strlen($contents)) {
    echo "Error reading data"l
}
else{
    $myjson = json_decode($contents);
    echo "<li>BPI:".$myjson->bpi->INR->rate;
    echo "<li>disclaimer:".$myjson->disclaimer;
}
```

Comment: when i m include this code reslut is blank page please give another solution sir

Comment: @shaikJilani You enabled `allow_url_fopen` or used the code?

Comment: <?php $url = "bitpay.com/api/rates";; $json = file_get_contents($url); $data = json_decode($json, TRUE);$rate3 = $data[3]["rate"]; $rate67 = $data[67]["rate"]; ?> <li style="list-style-type:none; color:#fff; font-weight:700">1BTC = <?php echo $rate67?>INR </li>                            how to wire for this code